Is there a way to make the legacy RESX editor the default in Visual Studio?
Visual Studio recently added a new "Resource Explorer" view as the default for opening up .RESX files.  I actually prefer the older, simpler legacy RESX editor view
I expected this to be an option that I could turn on or off.  But I don't see a checkbox for it in the "Preview Features" section.  It's just the default every time I double click.  Is there any way I can make the older one the default?
Right now the only way I can use the older view is to remember to right-click each time I want to open it up and choose "Open With", then "Managed Resources Editor (Legacy)"  I can live with that but it would be nice to not have to do this.


Is there a way to make the legacy RESX editor the default in Visual Studio?

Yes, you may use the legacy Managed Resource Editor experience through right clicking on a .resx (or .resw) file then Open With | Managed Resource Editor(Legacy) and click Set as Default.


Completely missed that button!  Thank you!
